# jQuery manipulation only once (JSF, Primefaces)

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a DataTable where I want to modify the font size. The user can set the font size with a selectOneMenue component.

Now if I update it with jQuery this only happens the first time. If I want to change the font size by the selectOneMenue the font size is set to default and if I make a refresh (F5) the font size is changed successfully. But I do not want this behaviour.

So I added the reload() function in the script part. If I do this I always get this Firefox Message if I want to reload..... and then it renders the table with default size and shortly after it renders the right font size. So the end product is ok but I do not want this firefox message to appear that has to be submitted and I also want to turn off the prerendering ot the table with the default font size.

Now I have this code

```
<script>
        jQuery(document)
                .ready(
                        function() {
                            jQuery('#dtSummary')
                                    .css('cssText',
                                            'font-size:#{summaryBean.selectedFont}px !important');

                        });

        function changeFont() {
            document.getElementById("dtSummary").style.fontSize = "#{summaryBean.selectedFont}px !important;}";
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    </script>


<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="rainstar-form-inline"
                columnClasses="rainstar-form-column-left rainstar-form-column-right">


                <p:selectOneMenu id="targ" effect="fade"
                    styleClass="rainstar-input-small2"
                    value="#{summaryBean.selectedFont}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{summaryBean.selectionFont_change}"
                    onchange="changeFont()">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{summaryBean.fontCollection}" />
                    <p:ajax update="dtSummary" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.button_print}" icon="ui-icon-print"
                styleClass="rainstar-button-right"
                action="#{summaryBean.generatePdf()}" ajax="false" />


            <p:dataTable id="dtSummary" styleClass="rainstar-form-margin-top"
                value="#{summaryBean.eintragList}"
                selection="#{summaryBean.selectedEintrag}" selectionMode="multiple"
                var="eintrag" rowKey="#{eintrag.it1}">

                <p:column id="header" styleClass="ui-state-default">
                    <div class="ui-dt-c">#{eintrag.it1}</div>
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="rainstar-table-item"
                    headerText="#{tableBundleBean.summary_table_nozzles} [mm]">
                    <h:outputText value="#{eintrag.it2}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:panelGroup>


    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need jquery here. Try:

```
<p:column styleClass="rainstar-table-item"
          headerText="#{tableBundleBean.summary_table_nozzles} [mm]">
   <h:outputText value="#{eintrag.it2}" style="font-size:#{summaryBean.selectedFont}px !important"/>
</p:column>
```

Jquery would make sense if you wanted to avoid server roundtrip and rendering for performance reasons for example. In such case the selectMenu widget should not cause a page refresh.

Comment: Maaannnn ^^ Thank you!! I do not know why I thought sooo complicated...  But I changed your solution a little bit. I do not use the style attribute on column level. I used it on the table. So I only needed to write it once.  <p:dataTable id="dtSummary" styleClass="rainstar-form-margin-top" value="#summaryBean.eintragList}" selection="#summaryBean.selectedEintrag}" selectionMode="multiple" var="eintrag" rowKey="#{eintrag.it1}" style="font-size:#{summaryBean.selectedFont}px !important">

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which ID will be generated for your select box, but assuming it will get id 'targ', something like the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(
  changeFontSize
)

function changeFontSize() {
  $('#dtSummary').css('fontSize', $('.targ').val() + 'px !important');
}
```